# Arithmetic operations in prolog

Tags: math, prolog, arithmetic-expressions

How is it possible to obtain 28 using 7 10 3 2 in this order and without using parentheses?I've been thinking for the past 1 1/2 hours and I couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post what you tried and explain why it does not work ?

Comment: Please turn this into a programming question. Currently it gives the impression of being a copy of a math puzzle, with a purely accidental tag of a random programming language.

Comment: @sutrivmz: `28 is *(7+10-3,2).`. Well, i used a parenthesis but not in the "arithmetic" sense.

Comment: @gusbro Why do you not consider that an answer?

Comment: Please define the allowed operations.

Comment: forget 7 : 7, 10 * 3 - 2 (works in C) you get 28.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it step by step, passing the changing state along.

```
step(S,A,X, S2,A2) :-
   (  S = [+ | S2], A2 is A + X
   ;  S = [- | S2], A2 is A - X
   ;  S = [* | S2], A2 is A * X
   ;  S = [/ | S2], A2 is A div X 
   ).

puzzle(S) :- 
   step(S,  7, 10,  S2, A2),
   step(S2, A2, 3,  S3, A3),
   step(S3, A3, 2,  [], 28).
```

Trying:

```
?- puzzle(X).
X = [+,-,*] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer builds on the previous one by @WillNess, trying to make it simpler:

```
x_y_xy(A, B, A + B).
x_y_xy(A, B, A - B).
x_y_xy(A, B, A * B).
x_y_xy(A, B, A div B).

puzzle(C) :- 
   x_y_xy(7, 10, A),
   x_y_xy(A, 3,  B),
   x_y_xy(B, 2,  C).
```

Sample use:

```
?- puzzle(Expr), Expr =:= 28.
Expr = (7+10-3)*2 ;
false.
```